# Find a string that contains only certain characters

Tags: regex

I have created a regular expression to find a string like

> [general_conf]

it looks like:

```
\[(.*)]
```

and it works, however I need to match only letters and _

tried: `\[(a-z_)]` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that is done by putting the wanted characters into a set of square brackets. So it should look something like this:

```
\[([a-z_]*)]
```

Maybe you are interested into a [quick introduction to regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4).

Another good source of regex information is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
/\[[a-z_]+\]/
```

hope this helps.